# How Update cell in datagridview after enter? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, data-binding, datagridview, keypress

i want update value from datagridview to sql after enter on cell. but it don't work.

**this code:**

```
Private Sub dgvShow_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles dgvShow.KeyPress

Dim sb3 As New StringBuilder
Dim da2 As New SqlDataAdapter

For i As Integer = 0 To dgvShow.Rows.Count - 2
            If dgvShow.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                sb3.Remove(0, sb3.Length())
                sb3.Append("UPDATE PositionLevelWelfare ")
                sb3.Append("SET wfDivision=@wfDivision,wfSection=@wfSection,wfPosition=@wfPosition,wfBaht=@wfBaht")
                sb3.Append(" FROM PositionLevelWelfare pw")
                sb3.Append(" WHERE pw.Run=@Run")
                Dim SqlEdit As String = ""
                SqlEdit = sb3.ToString()

                da2.SelectCommand.CommandText = SqlEdit
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Run", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dgvShow.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@wfDivision", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dgvShow.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@wfSection", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dgvShow.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@wfPosition", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dgvShow.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@wfBaht", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dgvShow.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
                da2.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear() 
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for tour time. :)

Comment: Where's the error? What have you tried?

Comment: no error and Nothing happen. i use code with button it's work. but i try change keypress it's not work. i don't know why it's not work.

Comment: You should save the changes on AfterEdit() or EndUpdate() (I don't recall the exact name). AFAIK the text on the cell does not update until you end editing it hence the  dgvShow.Rows(i).Cells(X).Value is binded to the "old" value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Events `DataGridView.CellBeginEdit` and `DataGRidView.CellEndEdit`
Then value updates after pressing Enter or **when you leaving a current cell**(click on other cell..)

In the handler of `DataGridView.CellBeginEdit`

In this handler we just save a current(old) value of cell
In this example I using a `DataGridView.Tag` property as place where to save a old value

```
Private Sub dgv_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellBeginEdit
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
    Me.dgv.Tag = Me.dgv.CurrentCell.Value
End Sub
```

Then in handler of `DataGRidView.CellEndEdit`

```
Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellEndEdit

    'Here you will get a new value of cell from dgv.CurrentCell.Value and compare with old value from dgv.Tag
    'You can add your checks for new value if you need. If some check fails just set
    dgv.CurrentCell.Value = dgv.Tag
    'If checks succeed then run your update to Database function with new value


End Sub
```

Or you can use `dgv.CellValidating` event, where you can use your check for new value and `Cancel` changes if you need. And after this in `CellEndEdit` jut run your UpdateTodatabase function
Remember `CellValidating` occur before `CellEndEdit`

[MSDN DataGridView.CellValidating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx)